# Register .NET 4.5 IIS 10 Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I've been looking at this for a few hours now and I cannot get it fixed.

I have a .NET 4.5 web site and API and I'm working on Windows 10.  I have VS2012 Pro installed and VS2015 Community installed.

Checking the Web Platform Installer it states that I already have .NET 4.5 installed.

Everytime I open the API or Web Site solutions it informs me that .NET 4.5 & IIS aren't configured and my applications wont run.

I've tried running these commands as per MS:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
```

And I still get the some error being reported.  Everything I have read states that the above command should fix the issue but it doesn't.  I can't find anything else on the topic other than the command listed above.

Seems there are a lot of people with this issue all saying the same thing but no working solution (at least for me so far).  .NET 4.5 isn't listed in `Add Features to Windows`.

How do I get this working so that ASP.NET 4.5 and IIS work?

Comment: So who down-voted this and why?

Comment: Yeah, I'm having the same problem. This is a good question and you've clearly shown research. I even tried doing the `aspnet_regiis -iru` and no luck. Sometimes downvoters gonna h8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems this is actually a bug.  Despite the command actually working older version of Visual Studio can encounter an issue once .NET 4.6 is installed.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/11/11/dialog-box-may-be-displayed-to-users-when-opening-projects-in-microsoft-visual-studio-after-installation-of-microsoft-net-framework-4-6.aspx

Microsoft has published a fix for all impacted versions of Microsoft Visual Studio.

- VS2013 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2994375
- VS2012 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002339
- VS2010 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002340

Comment: As far as I know there is not an issue to fix for VS2015.  Microsoft hasn't released a fix as far as I know.

Comment: The other fixes (numerous) didn't work. Only this hotfix did. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

I had the same issues which I have since fixed in **VS 2015**, my situation was:

1. Update from Windows 7 --> Windows 10
2. Installed VS 2015
3. Enabled IIS so I could then open the management console & do lovely things
4. I then tried to host a .net 4.5 Web API in my local IIS mentioned above

Result was **404** errors.

To fix:

1. Open the **Developer Command Prompt for VS2015** as **Administrator**
2. Run `dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45`
3. The operation completed successfully

Lovely 200 responses...

Comment: Indeed.  I blogged about it and am getting hundreds of clicks a day ... ! http://www.jammer.biz/enable-asp-net-on-windows-10/

Comment: Worked for  me. It downloads Image Service and Management Tool (image version 10.0.10586.0). It's s small download that took around 3 minutes for me.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Comment: Still relevant as of November 2019. Especially helpful if you are installing older software (looking at you Ektron 9.2) that is dependent on finding ASP.NET 4.5 and is not happy with 4.8+ and associated reg key(s). Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

To fix:

1. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 as Administrator
2. Run `dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45`
3. The operation completed successfully

Comment: I think you need to read the question again.  I had already performed these steps ...

Comment: I think this answer is directly copied from Neil almost 3 hours later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command (using CMD run as Admin) :

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerRole
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServer
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIFilter
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIExtensions
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
```

or using Powershell run as Admin :

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerRole /featurename:WAS-WindowsActivationService /featurename:WAS-ProcessModel /featurename:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /featurename:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /featurename:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /featurename:IIS-ASPNET /featurename:IIS-DefaultDocument /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /featurename:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /featurename:IIS-ISAPIFilter /featurename:IIS-RequestFiltering /featurename:IIS-Metabase /featurename:IIS-WMICompatibility /featurename:IIS-LegacyScripts /featurename:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /featurename:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /featurename:IIS-HttpTracing
```

Make sure there are no errors after execution. If there is an error, it's very easy, you just need to install manualy the prerequisite feature according to the error message that appears.