# The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context when including System.IO.Compression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5

I"m currently running .net version 4.5 and am trying to use it's "new" zip functions. I'm including `System.IO.Compression` and am trying to run the following code:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

The issue I'm getting is that `The name 'ZipFile does not exist in the current context`. I don't know why it wouldn't exist if I'm already using what requires it.

Comment: @Tinwor Not a duplicate, I'm already referencing the namespace but am still getting errors.

Comment: @JoeScotto you need to reference the *assembly* - most likely. Right click on "references" in your project, click "Add Reference" then file the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly. Then you can use the namespace.

Comment: You are referecing the wrong library. It's `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

Comment: @vcsjones I'm not using a solution or a project, I'm using just a standalone handler.ashx file.

Comment: The dupe has the same namespace/assembly problem. The specifics of adding assemblies to an ashx are a separate issue, may deserve their own question.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the namespace to your current file?  To do this add this to the top of the file.

```
 using System.IO.Compression;
```

Comment: That's what I currently have.

Comment: Then see the other answer.  To add the reference to your project right click References under your project and click Add Reference.  Then select Assemblies on the left and find System.IO.Compression.FileSystem. Check that box and click OK.

Comment: It's just a standalone handler.ashx file though, no solution or project.

Comment: In Visual Studio click Solution Explorer on the right.  This should expand a menu.  Do you not see anything in there?

Comment: Solution 'Solution1' (0 projects)

Comment: So I'm going to say it will be significantly easier for you going forward (not just for this one thing) to make a project.  It will give you much more control over what's going on.  A new project will have a bunch of stuff you don't need in it but once you get it all set up this will be a simple matter.  That said you can use this page to learn about adding assembly references using a web.config file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37e2zyhb(v=vs.85).aspx  Web.config is similar to PHP.ini.

Comment: What would be a good project type that I can add my existing html and css files to?

Comment: Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) should do.  I believe there's some check boxes for various technologies you'll not want.  Once you have that all set then add your assembly reference and you're off to the races.  To compile your project right click it and click Publish.  A file system publish is the easiest one.

Comment: What about adding my current files to that new project?

Comment: You can drag and drop the files into the project.  Add Existing Files is another option. If you drag a folder in it tends to add the folder but not the contents, Show All Files gets around this (see the tiny buttons at the top of the Solution Explorer.)

Comment: I have everything setup now and added the reference to System.IO.Compression.Filesystem but still get that error....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136582/discussion-between-licht-and-joe-scotto).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a reference to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly. However the namespace is still `System.IO.Compression`.

See [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.