# 404.3 when accessing Web Forms page on IIS on Windows 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I looked up several threads and tried this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716434/register-net-4-5-iis-10-windows-10) but no success. I want to run aspx pages via IIS server on Windows 10.

Error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>
> The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Comment: hmmm... IIS configuration ?

Comment: its a fresh install, so configuration is default, any specific setting I should tell you?

Comment: You want to run it from within the server or from another machine ?

Comment: it's a dev machine, so running within the server.

Comment: i created a project in visual studio and published it to IIS but IIS still can't run, I believe there's some mapping and module add setting, please advise

Comment: Open windows feature, and go to IIS node, make sure aspnet related features are enabled.