# Unable to enable ASP.NET 4.5 with either DISM or Turn Windows features on or off

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-10

We have been unable to enable ASP.NET 4.5 on Windows 10. We are needing to enable it, in order to run ASP.NET web applications on IIS.

We are using IIS v 10.0.16299.15 and are running Windows 10 Pro.

**We have tried using "Turn Windows features on or off".**

```
Internet Information Services
    World Wide Web Services
        Application Development Features
            ASP.NET 4.7
```

The above appears to work; it says, "Windows completed the requested changes," and asks us to restart the computer. After the restart, when we return to "Turn Windows features on or off", ASP.NET 4.7 is listed as disabled (whereas we would expect it to be enabled.)

**We have also tried using the DISM command line tool.**

```
PS C:\> dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45                           

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool                                                                                          
Version: 10.0.16299.15                                                                                                                  

Image Version: 10.0.16299.64                                                                                                            

Enabling feature(s)                                                                                                                     
[==========================100.0%==========================]                                                                            

Error: 50                                                                                                                               

The operation is complete but IIS-ASPNET45 feature was not enabled.                                                                     
A required parent feature may not be enabled. You can use the /enable-feature /all option to automatically enable each parent feature fr
om the following list. If the parent feature(s) are already enabled, refer to the log file for further diagnostics.                     
IIS-ISAPIFilter, IIS-ISAPIExtensions, IIS-NetFxExtensibility45                                                                          

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

**How do we enable ASP.NET 4.5 on Windows 10?**

We tried the answers here [Register .NET 4.5 IIS 10 Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716434/register-net-4-5-iis-10-windows-10). Unfortunately, running `dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45` from a **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017** results in the same error.

**Edit**:

These are the WARNING and ERROR messages in the log file.

> 2017-12-11 18:07:47, Warning               DISM   DISM OS Provider: PID=11888 TID=11856 Unable to set the DLL search path to the servicing stack folder. C:\Windows may not point to a valid Windows folder. - CDISMOSServiceManager::Final_OnConnect
>
> 2017-12-11 18:07:47, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=11888 TID=11856 Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Temp\382E1E51-CDE6-4CFC-8840-8EC85D283DB5\PEProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
>
> 2017-12-11 18:07:47, Warning               DISM   DISM Provider Store: PID=11888 TID=11856 Failed to load the provider: C:\Users\MY_USER\AppData\Local\Temp\382E1E51-CDE6-4CFC-8840-8EC85D283DB5\EmbeddedProvider.dll. - CDISMProviderStore::Internal_GetProvider(hr:0x8007007e)
>
> 2017-12-11 18:07:48, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11888 TID=11856 Parent features must be enabled before this feature can be enabled. "IIS-ASPNET45" - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange
>
> 2017-12-11 18:07:48, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11888 TID=11856 One or more features could not be enabled. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ProcessFeatureChange(hr:0x80070032)
>
> 2017-12-11 18:07:48, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=11888 TID=11856 Failed while processing command enable-feature. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070032)

Comment: and what the log says?

Comment: @derloopkat I'll start adding more details about the logs. Thank you for asking.

Comment: you might be interested in posting your question at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I've tested it and for me the command works fine.

Comment: It turns out that my Windows10 system was corrupted. Restoring the OS fixed the problem.

Comment: post all steps you did to fix it in an answer

Comment: @magicandre1981 Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our "Turn Windows features on or off" feature was corrupted. Resetting the PC resolved the problem.

1. Press the Windows key.
2. Type "Reset this PC" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Click "Get Started"
4. Click "Remove everything" (it will probably also work with Keep my files)

Continue with the steps to reset the PC. The reset will take about an hour. Afterward, reinstall your software suite of preference.

Note: We tried a collection of other incantations with `sfc` and `dsim` for about two hours before using the above nuclear option.

Comment: CBS (Component Based Setup) of Windows is more fragile than previous technologies, so yes resetting Windows is more often than it should.